# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ is not exact.

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ is not exact.

I am trying to find an exact sequence such that if we apply the functor above we don't get an exact sequence. It is known that the functor above is exact from the right so I am just trying to prove that the first map does not maintain injectivity. I took the following sequence:

$$0 \longrightarrow 3\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 6\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow 0$$

where $f: 3\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 6\mathbb{Z}$ is given by $f(z) = 2z$. 
Clearly this is a short exact sequence. Now if we look at the map:

$$ f_* : \mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_\mathbb{Z} 3\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_\mathbb{Z}6\mathbb{Z} $$

it is the zero map because the tensor product on the right is null. But the tensor on the left is not null so this means that $ker (f_*) \neq {0}$ so $f_*$ is not injective.

I want to ask if this solution is correct or I did something stupid. Can someone verify and if there is a better example please provide it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think the left tensor product is not-null but the right one is?

Comment: Main issue:  $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} -$ is a functor, so it preserves isomorphisms.  Your map $f$ is an iso, so $f_*$ is too.

Comment: Hint consider $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$ where the first nontrivial map is multiplication by 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your example is an example:  your map $f$ is an iso of abelian groups, so $f_*$ is as well.  This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}-$ is a functor, so it respects isos.

Moreover, because tensoring respects isos, and each of your groups $3\mathbb{Z}$ and $6\mathbb{Z}$ are infinite cyclic (hence iso to each other), their tensor products are iso:  you cannot have one null and the other not.

The standard example of this is to consider the canonical sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to  \mathbb{Z}  \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0
$$
which "creates" $\mathbb{Z_2}$ as the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  So, the second arrow is multiplication by $2$ and the third is the quotient map.  Apply your functor $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}-$  and use the usual isos to get
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0
$$
which will NEVER be short exact, no matter the maps (for counting/quotient reasons).

Comment: The usual example is always using $\mathbb{Z}$ and the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Are there any other concrete examples involving fields, algebras, and modules over algebras? Thanks.

Comment: That would depend on what you’re trying to disprove and what category you’re in.

Comment: I am working in the category of modules over group algebra over arbitrary field. The group is finite group. The functor is the field (seen as trivial representation) tensored (over the group algebra) with an object, and it is of course a right exact functor, but I cannot seem to find examples, which are such field, group, and initial sequence, to show it is not left exact. $\mathbb{Z}$ definitely does not suit. Maybe some infinite field?